WritableManifest has invalid value in DBT 1.8
Current Behavior :
WritableManifest has invalid value when upgrading dbt version from 1.4 to 1.8 in jenkins
Steps To Reproduce :
setup dbt 1.4.3 with incremental model
upgrade the setup to 1.8 version it will be required to add on_schema_change parameter so add on_schema_change parameter
trigger command
dbt build --threads 8 --exclude resource_type:seed resource_type:test --select @state:new @state:modified.body @state:modified.configs @state:modified.macros --state ./dbt-artifacts --vars {"full_data": false}

Expected Behavior :
manifest.json should get created without error
